# How should I make my files accessible to my virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine

I want to install development tools in my virtual machine, but i am having trouble sharing my files to my virtual machine? Any steps on how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy all ur files into a folder
2. Right click that folder
3. Choose Sharing Tab
4. Check Share this folder
5. Aplly, OK
6. Go to ur virtual machine, Start -> run -> \your machine ip -> Enter
7. Copy the folder into ur virtual machine.

Comment: That's not always the case.  You're assuming that (a) the guest OS has a networking client and (b) the guest's networking client can get to the host's shares.  VirtualBox has a "Shared Folders" mechanism, but that only works if there are Guest Additions for the guest OS.